# apt-get update is not working

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

apt-get update
Err:1 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  403  Forbidden
Hit:2 http://old.kali.org/kali sana InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text; just post the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your first and second lines are wrong. The correct line is `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free` (You probably don't need the second line.) Source: [The Kali Rolling Repository](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

You have no need to include the third and fourth lines. They link to the RETIRED Kali sana repository. DON'T MIX YOUR REPOSITORIES!